# passing value server to client in method meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, methods, serial-port

client side code

```
Template.hello.events({
 "click": function () {
  Meteor.call('Message',function(result){
  alert(result);
 });
```

server side method call

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {

Meteor.methods({
 'Message':function(){
 SerialPort.list(function (err, ports) {

 ports.forEach(function(port) {
 console.log(port.comName);  
  var atxt =  port.comName;
  return atxt ;
 });//ports end
 });  //list end
 }   //message end
 }); //method end
 }   //server end
```

The above programme 'undefined' print the alert box client side . return atxt not returned any value. please help me **meteor** apllication passing server side return value access the client side !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when Meteor `server side` methods returns some data, client side need to fetch that `asynchronously` via a callback. And in that callback, there need to have two parameters, `error and result`. Basically the second parameter is your result and the first one is `error` (if any). So, you need to update your client side code accordingly. Besides before returning from server side ,just `console.log` your data so that you can be sure of the result.

```
Meteor.call('Message',function(err,result){
    if(!err) {
        alert(result);
    } else {console.log(err);}
});
```